# How to customize the Plaid widget element

Tags: plaid

Is there any way to customize the plaid widget element from application in Angular ?
Here I am trying to change the color of "Continue" button. Can anyone suggest ?

[Plaid Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jksDo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize parts of the widget from the [Plaid dashboard](https://dashboard.plaid.com/link) -- however the color of the Continue button can't be customized.